# How do I "mark" a message sent by the user, and not just receive it as if it's from someone else?

Tags: c#, .net, udp, console-application, chat

Currently when sending a message in this simple C# application, it receives the message as if from another computer on the network. Now, if I want to make it say for example: "Me: sampleMessage" instead of just spitting out the IP and Port, how could I accomplish that without rewriting the entire program?

I've already tried to compare the 'ep' to the 'groupEP' to look for similar adress/port, but to no avail.

```cs
namespace ChattApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int ListenPort = 11000;
        public static IPEndPoint epTemp;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var listenThread = new Thread(Listener);
            listenThread.Start();

            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            socket.EnableBroadcast = true;
            IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 11000);

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write(">");
                string msg = Console.ReadLine();

                byte[] sendbuf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
                socket.SendTo(sendbuf, ep);
                epTemp = ep;
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
        }

        static void Listener()
        {
            UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(ListenPort);

            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, ListenPort);
                    byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);

                    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

                    Console.WriteLine("{0} at {1}: {2}\n", groupEP.ToString(), dt.ToString("HH:mm"),
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                listener.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You would have to modify the sendbuf to include that additional information.

Comment: @jdweng But wouldn't that just change the message? The program would still echo my IP and Port right before the message

Comment: Do it on the other end of the connection could change the receive message.